# Visible on inside for loop in beamer produces errors

Tags: beamer, pgfplots, overlays

I am trying to create a plot where the points would be added sequentially over multiple slides. But the added code produces a bunch of `Undefined control sequence.` errors.

Interestingly, when I use `\x` and `\xi` as the variable and the index variable respectively in the for loop, the code starts running and I get a huge 250+ page PDF! It's filled with empty plots except the very last page where the plot has all the points.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.18}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Frame name}
        \begin{figure}
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \begin{axis}
                    \foreach \point [count = \pointindex] in {-2, 5, -1}
                    {
                        \addplot [
                            only marks,
                            mark = *,
                            samples at = {\point},
                            visible on = <\pointindex->,
                        ]
                        {x^2};
                    }
                \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{figure}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, that `\pointindex` is defined locally to the `\foreach` loop. But for overlays you need global values. You can use something like:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.18}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Frame name}
        \begin{figure}
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \begin{axis}
                    \foreach \point [count = \pointindex] in {-2, 5, -1}
                    {
                      \xdef\ADDPLOT{%
                        \noexpand\addplot[visible on = {<\pointindex->},
                          only marks,
                          mark = *,
                          samples at = {\point}
                        ]
                      } 
                      \ADDPLOT {x^2};
                    }
                \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{figure}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: three frames]

Comment: Neat solution. Any idea why changing the macro names makes it go haywire? After all, those macro names are precisely what the PGF manual uses (the section on package `pgffor`).

Comment: @Saptam `\xi` is already defined (`\mathchar"118`) outside the loop and can be interpreted by `visbile on`. Depending on the outside definition of the index variable macro you would get different result. Sometimes with, sometimes without error message. But always more or less an accident.